# I'm trying to install pySurvival but this error appears

Tags: python, terminal, pip, environment

```
               ^      `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9661:22: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                       ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
         PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
         ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
  #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9661:52: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                     ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
        PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
        ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
  #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9661:52: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                     ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
        ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
               ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9661:52: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                     ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
         PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
         ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
  #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9677:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                           ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
        PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
        ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
  #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9677:26: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                           ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
        ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
               ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9677:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                           ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
         PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
         ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
  #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9677:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                            ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
        PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
        ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
  #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9677:59: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                            ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
        ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
               ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pysurvival/cpp_extensions/_non_parametric.cpp:9677:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                            ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
         PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
         ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
  #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
  ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  12 warnings and 2 errors generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysurvival
Running setup.py clean for pysurvival
Failed to build pysurvivalyour text`

Don't know what to do, somebody please help

I am expecting to be able to install pySurvival to use its methods

Comment: Could you tell us what OS you are running, the version of gcc, python and pip you have installed?

Comment: "warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated" means that you should not use that function because it will be removed in the future, instead you should read the docs from the library and find the new function to do the same.

Comment: @Razzer The OP doesn't use the function, the OP is just trying to compile existing package using `pip install pysurvival`

Comment: Maybe updating pip then, like Paolo Sini said.

Comment: @Razzer Couldn't help to compile C-API code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have ran across the same problem for a lot of different libraries recently. I am guessing that you use Python 3.11. Can you try downgrading your Python to 3.9 and also make sure that pip (or pip3) version matches with Python version and then try to install the library?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems the OP already uses 3.9: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9`

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! If so, It might be that the pip version does not match 3.9. I have just tried to debug the same error message yesterday and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There was only one release of PySurvival in 2019 (0.1.2), and it is compatible with Python 2.7-3.7. The author of the question used Python 3.9, so if you encounter a similar problem, create an environment with Python 3.7 or use other packages such as lifelines or scikit-survival.